# How to force neato engine to reverse node order?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to draw a graph where the shorter word "Myth" is in the top right, however the neato engine is recalcitrant and refuses to accept pos inputs (with or without !) and rank inputs. When appending ! to my pos inputs, it will just stretch the graph out really far, and keep "Hominids" in the top row, while putting "Myth" in the bottom.

[image]

```
digraph G {
layout="neato";
center="true";
fontpath="C:\Windows\Fonts";
node [fontsize="14"];
node [fontname="Abode Jenson Pro"];
graph [size="10,10!"];
rankdir=LR;
meme [shape=ellipse,label="Myth",rank="min",pos="3,0!"];
gene [shape=ellipse,label="Hominids",rank="max",pos="7,10!"];
meme -> gene [arrowsize="0.5",label="increases \n survival of",fontsize="8",constraint="true"];
gene -> meme [arrowsize="0.5",label="  generate \n venerate",fontsize="8",constraint="false"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Graphviz counts coordinates as on the orthogonal graph with **0** being at the bottom left corner. So in `pos` attribute first coordinate is distance **from left side to right →**, and the second one — **from bottom to top ↑**.

Look at you current coordinate values:

[image]

So it's logical that your nodes appear as on the picture: you've forced their positions to be so! If you inverse the `pos` values you will get the result you need:

```
digraph G {
    layout="neato";
    center="true";
    fontpath="C:\Windows\Fonts";
    node [fontsize="14"];
    node [fontname="Abode Jenson Pro"];
    graph [size="10,10!"];
    meme [shape=ellipse,label="Myth",rank="min",pos="7,10"];
    gene [shape=ellipse,label="Hominids",rank="max",pos="3,0"];
    meme -> gene [arrowsize="0.5",label="increases \n survival of",fontsize="8",constraint="true"];
    gene -> meme [arrowsize="0.5",label="  generate \n venerate",fontsize="8",constraint="false"];
}
```

[image]

Also note that [rankdir](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir) attribute you used, won't have any effect in neato. As stated in the documentation it only works with **dot** layout.

Comment: Oh thanks a bunch! I kept fussing with it for some time after posting the question and have come to the conclusion that neato will require more practice to use. If you'd like, in my further forays into graphviz, I ran into the next problem where it just really wanted to plant the edge on the left side of the graph, while I wanted it on the right (for visual reasons). Using invisible nodes etc didn't help at all, and when using directional attachment in dot it would do a squiggly line (as in photo attached).

https://i.imgur.com/4gNsXwN.png

I understand it uses weights for the edges.